# Responsive method to disable and enable submit upon Ajax start-stop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried the following methods:

1) Show/Hide

```
$('button').ajaxStart(function() {
 $(this).hide();
});
$('button').ajaxStop(function() {
 $(this).show();
});
```

2) Visible/Hidden

```
$('button').ajaxStart(function() {
 $(this).css({visibility, 'hidden'});
});
$('button').ajaxStop(function() {
 $(this).css({visibility, 'visible'});
});
```

3) Add/Remove Class

```
$('button').ajaxStart(function() {
 $(this).addClass('invisible');
});
$('button').ajaxStop(function() {
 $(this).removeClass('invisible');
});
```

4) Enable/Disable

```
$('button').ajaxStart(function() {
 $(this).attr('disabled','disabled')
});
$('button').ajaxStop(function() {
 $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

So far, only the Show/Hide method is responsive enough to be executed under 1s. The rest took between 1-2s, which is noticeably long. However, I would like the button to be displayed but disabled with some noticeable CSS change. Is there a more responsive way to enable and disable the submit button temporarily?

Comment: What browser are you using? Most class changes apply instantly, depending, of course, how huge your page is

Comment: @semyon, Firefox 17.0. The HTML is 6.9kB, not big, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("button").click(function() {

    // disable the submit button before the ajax call...
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yoururl.html',
        data: {},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response){
            // enable the submit button after ajax call success...
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        },
        error: function(){
            // error process here
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should adopt this approach to disable the button at the earliest opportunity.